# Области видимости Kotlin внутри пакета

Tags: kotlin, классы, область-видимости

У меня имеется 1 пакет, в нем существует 2 класса:

```
package animals.cat

class CatA {

    fun a1()
    {
        println ("a1")
    }
    fun a2()
    {
        println("a2")
    }
}
```

и

```
package animals.cat


class CatB {

    fun b1()
    {
        CatA.a1()
    }
    fun b2()
    {
        println("b2")
    }

}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что система не видит обращение CatA.a1(). Что я делаю не так, почему метод класса не виден? Также пытался создавать отдельный объект класса CatA и делать запрос к методу через него, таким образом тоже не работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через отдельный объект все работает

```
fun b1()
{
    val a = CatA()
    a.a1()
}
```

Вызов

```
fun main(){
    val b = CatB()
    b.b1()
}
```

Comment: Оказалось, что пакета недостаточно для взаимодействия, необходим прямой импорт класса, чего я хотел избежать. Благодарю